# paginated result for related field in django?

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following models.

```
Class Blog:
  pass

class Entry:
  models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

I want to do something like this

> - filter & sort blog by some criteria
> - get related entries for page 2

Can I do something better than below?

```
blog_ids = Blog.objects.filter(q).order_by(order)
entry_qs = Entry.objects.filter(id__in=blog_ids)
paginator = Paginator(entry_qs)
entries = paginator.page(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `order_by` on the entries rather than the blog object. An easier way of implmenting sorting and pagination of blog entries would be using a class based view like ListView. For eg. in your views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Entry

class BlogView(ListView):
    queryset = Entry.objects.order_by("-date")
    paginate_by = 10
```

You will need to mention it in the urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', BlogView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

Now, if you use a url like `/page=1` it will show the second page of entries (passed as `object_list`)